# Enable Security boot, failed to install Ubuntu 20.04 with Elkhart Lake chipset

Tags: intel

1. Download ubuntu 20.04 ISO from here: https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-iot

a. https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/release/inteliotg/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64+intel-iot.iso?_gl=1*1l53hco*_gcl_au*NTc0MjU2MDQuMTcwOTAwMzIzMA..&_ga=2.162162748.1461495715.1709003217-247405748.1706173164

2. Make ISO image to USB Storage
3. Enable Security boot at BIOS
4. Boot from USB Storage, prompt error message, can't install.
   [Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV9b4.png)
   =>Disable Security boot at BIOS, install normal.

We need to install Ubuntu OS with security boot enabled, how do we achieve this?

Comment: You can enable secure boot after installing

Comment: enable secure boot after installing
=>Occurred other error message

"error: bad shim signature" **
"error: you need to load the kernel first"

Comment: You need to boot to UEFI and set whatever secure boot setting to allow the shim. Perhaps it's named partner or something that's in between the other options that are microsoft and disabled.